# LLVM: object file relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata'

Tags: c, llvm, ld, relocation

I have an LLVM program that evaluates instructions and builds IR. I then emit the module using `LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile`. When linking with `ld` I get an outut of:

```
test:(.text+0x61): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata'
test:(.text+0x6d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata'+4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The cause of this error comes from a global variable I create in the program. When outputting the IR you see:

```
@const.array = private unnamed_addr constant [6 x i8] c"\05\06\07\08\09\0A", align 16
```

The code I use to output the object file:

```c
LLVMTargetRef t;
LLVMGetTargetFromTriple(LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple(), &t, &error);
if (error)
    printf("%s\n", error);

LLVMTargetMachineRef target = LLVMCreateTargetMachine(t, LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple(), LLVMGetTargetName(t), LLVMGetHostCPUFeatures(), LLVMCodeGenLevelNone, LLVMRelocStatic, LLVMCodeModelDefault);
strcpy(file_name + len, ".o\0");
LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile(target, mod, file_name, LLVMObjectFile, &error);
```

I'm using ld provided by cygwin. If I use ld in WSL it links fine. Also I tried using the `-m` option with ld but the cygwin version only seems to supprt i386 for some reason. I've tried different relocation modes in `LLVMCreateTargetMachine` but that didn't seem to do anything. How can I fix this?

Also a side question: When using `LLVMConsArray` it produces an ascii string as seen above but when I emit IR code for a c file in clang it uses an actual array. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Relocation errors tend to occur when you make a shared library, but didn't use `-fPIC` for the object files ...

Comment: Ah the relocation mode of default in the ```LLVMCreateTargetMachine``` seemed to be producing PIC object files. Using ```LLVMRelocDynamicNoPic``` it worked.